# Change the default behavior of my own classes to output value

Tags: java, operator-overloading, java-6

I am creating a mini class in Java:

```
public class ObjectInfo {
    public Object value = null;
    public Boolean isMax = null;
}
```

I want to make it so this class will output `value` whenever I call an instance.

Example:

```
public final void testSomething() {
    ObjectInfo actual = new OjbectInfo(11f, true);
    assertEquals(11f, (Float) actual);
}
```

I would like to make the class such that when I call `actual` like above, it knows to extract out the `value` parameter.

Is there any way to do this?

What I'd also like to do is say

`actual = 1234f`

I would like Java to know to shove that value into `value` and

`actual = false`

Put that into `isMax`

I know this can be done in C++ with operator overloading, but I can't seem to find anything on it for Java, at least on Google...

Comment: I noticed I got flagged down... I think that is slightly unfair since I just didn't know this fact in Java (got mixed up with c++). I was able to overcome my issues using various Number class manipulation. Kind of hokey but it still works great and fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this in Java. Instead you should add setter and getter methods or the properties you want to access. For example #setFloat( float value ) and #getFloat(). Then write test something like this:

```
assertEquals( 11f, actual.getFloat() );
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Java doesn't have user-definable operator overloading.

The best you could do is add an `asFloat()` method.